# MYSQL fulltext index exists but showing error 1191

Tags: php, mysql

I was successfully using below query in earlier version of Wamp Server (2.5) until upgraded to version 3.0.

This query works fine on actual server but gets failed on local server. I thought may be something wrong with tables hence imported all actual server tables to local server but still not working.

I'am very much sure that all indexes exists & all tables are using MyISAM engine.

**Indexes list:**

1) uk.Keyword_Name in e_pj_keywords uk table

2) a.company_name & a.company_type in post_jobs a table

3) j.location_name in locations j table

I have already used reference to all questions of stackoverflow & google to solve this error but couldn't.

Also enabled KEYS for all related tables but nothing worked.

```
Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I know there will be very minor error but unable to catch it. pls help.

**below is my query**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
*
FROM
(SELECT 
    a.job_id,
        a.Employer_ID,
        a.Sub_user_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.creation_on, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Created_date,
        DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(a.creation_on)) AS Posted_days,
        a.Job_type,
        a.Designation,
        a.Open_Positions,
        a.Job_Description,
        a.Min_age,
        a.Max_age,
        a.min_exp,
        a.max_exp,
        a.Hide_Salary,
        a.company_name,
        a.company_type,
        a.About_Company,
        a.Contact_person_name,
        a.Contact_No,
        a.Refresh_type,
        a.Response_type,
        a.Job_status,
        DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(a.creation_on)) AS Days_last_Login,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.Education ORDER BY pjedu.Education_ID SEPARATOR ', ') user_education
            FROM e_pj_edu pjedu INNER JOIN education g ON FIND_IN_SET(g.Edu_ID, pjedu.Education_ID)
            WHERE a.job_id = pjedu.Job_ID LIMIT 1
        ) AS Education,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.FA_description ORDER BY uf.FA_ID SEPARATOR ', ') FA
            FROM e_pj_fa uf INNER JOIN functional_area h ON FIND_IN_SET(h.FA_ID, uf.FA_ID)
            WHERE a.Job_ID = uf.Job_ID LIMIT 1
        ) AS FA_description,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.Industry_description ORDER BY ui.Industry_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Industry_ID
            FROM e_pj_industry ui INNER JOIN industry i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.Industry_ID, ui.Industry_ID)
            WHERE a.Job_ID = ui.Job_ID LIMIT 1
        ) AS Industry_description,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.location_name ORDER BY upl.Location_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Location_ID
            FROM e_pj_locations upl INNER JOIN locations j ON FIND_IN_SET(j.location_id, upl.Location_ID)
            WHERE a.Job_ID = upl.Job_ID LIMIT 1
        ) AS location_name,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uk.Keyword_Name ORDER BY uk.Keyword_ID SEPARATOR ', ') keyskills
            FROM e_pj_keywords uk WHERE a.Job_ID = uk.Job_ID LIMIT 1
        ) AS Keyword_Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cc.salary_description ORDER BY cc.salary_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Min_salary,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dd.salary_description ORDER BY dd.salary_ID SEPARATOR ', ') Max_salary
FROM
    post_jobs a
INNER JOIN user_salary cc ON FIND_IN_SET(cc.salary_ID, a.Min_salary)
INNER JOIN user_salary dd ON FIND_IN_SET(dd.salary_ID, a.Max_salary)
GROUP BY a.Job_id) aa
WHERE
MATCH (Keyword_Name) AGAINST ('"operation","mis","facility","sales"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (company_name, Designation) AGAINST ('"operation","mis","facility","sales"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND max_exp <= 11
AND MATCH (location_name) AGAINST ('"delhi","mumbai","navi,mumbai"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND Job_status = 'Active'
ORDER BY aa.Created_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

**Show create for relevant tables**

```
e_pj_keywords   CREATE TABLE `e_pj_keywords` (
`Keyword_ID` bigint(18) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Job_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Keyword_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Keyword_ID`),
 KEY `Job_ID` (`Job_ID`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `Keyword_Name` (`Keyword_Name`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1404 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


post_jobs   CREATE TABLE `post_jobs` (
`Job_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Designation` text,
`Company_Name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`company_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Job_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `Company_Name` (`Company_Name`),
FULLTEXT KEY `Designation` (`Designation`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=176 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1     


locations   CREATE TABLE `locations` (
`location_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`location_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Nation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `location_name` (`location_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: show the `show create` for the relevant tables, and note that `fulltext` indexes are NOT the same as a regular index/key. you have to explicitly specify a fulltext index.

Comment: Hi Marc, have edited Show Create for all relevant tables.

Answer (score 0):

Given those table descriptions, this is your problem:

```
OR MATCH (company_name, Designation) AGAINST 
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You don't have any single `FULLTEXT` index that includes both of those fields. MySQL will not combine two separate fulltext indexes together for the query - if you're doing a multifield `match`, then there has to be a SINGLE fulltext index that includes both of those fields in the same index.

You'd have to split the match up for each index, or create a new index that includes both fields, e.g.

```
... MATCH 'foo' AGAINST (company_name) OR MATCH 'foo' AGAINST (desgination)
```

or

```
FULLTEXT KEY `foo` (company_name, designation)
```

Comment: @Mark, I have tested first option but still showing similar error. Moreover i have tried by removing multiple fulltext search of company name & designation (only keyword fulltext used) but it didn't worked either. surprisingly it's working fine on live server without any error. I'am guessing there is some feature with wampserver 3 which i am missing though i have installed it successfully post installing all redistributable frameworks. don't know...but it's bothering me. last option would be going back to wamp Server 2.5. By the way i'am using Window 10

Comment: Finally, Wamp Server 3.0 experience was quite bitter in terms of Mysql queries. I uninstalled it & reinstalled version 2.5 & surprisingly same query started working again. Most probably i'am logging this bug with Wamp server 3 forum, referencing this question. Thanks @Mark for your help.